# Single login action for signup, password_resets, confirmations (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, session-cookies, dry

In my app a user is considered logged in (has a session) if there is a cookie set with their unique user_id_token (a UUID).  I have a before_action in the ApplicationController that requires a current user or else it logs the user out.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :require_user

  def require_user
    if current_user
      true
    else
      flash[:error] = "No user found"
      redirect_to logout_path
    end
  end

  # Who is currently logged in?
  def current_user
    if cookies.signed[:user_id_token]
      @current_user ||= User.find_by_id_token!(cookies.signed[:user_id_token])
    end
  end
  helper_method :current_user
end
```

There are several ways a user can create a session:

**(1) Login via email/password combo**

This is the "common" way of logging into the app.  You enter your email/password, and they are POSTed via a form to an action that authenticates you and lets you into the app by setting cookie[:user_id_token].

**(2) Password reset**

If a user forgets their password and resets it, they enter their new (valid) password and are then "authenticated" by setting cookie[:user_id_token]. However, a password reset isn't POSTing to the authentication method because they've already "authenticated" themselves by utilizing a unique password_reset_token sent to their email which provided the unique URL to change their password.

**(3) Confirming a new user**

Very similar to (2) above, a user is sent an invitation email containing a unique confirmation_token URL that allows them to finish their signup process.  Once they have finished confirming who they are (by selecting a valid password), they are "authenticated" and let into the app by setting the cookie[:user_id_token].

---

The problem is that there are 3 ways to get into the app by setting the cookie.  That's 3 places where I have very similar code `cookie[:user_id_token] = user.user_id_token`.

How can I have a SINGLE GATEKEEPER to let users into my app?

I have a `SessionsController` that I'm trying to use as the single path, but the `create_session` method (setting of the cookie[:user_id_token]) would have to be POSTed to from the login form and GETed with a token ID param on the password_reset/confirmation pages.

How can I keep the code DRY and reduce complexity by having a single access point to my app?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my own solution; putting the single "login" action into the application_controller.rb file and calling it from respective controllers when appropriate.  That way the login code (setting of the cookie, etc...) is all in a single location and isn't spread across several different controllers.